# cell value returns to original state after closing the program

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, openpyxl

So I'm trying to make a program that can edit cell values but apparently when I edit a cell its value changes In the program but not in excel spreadsheet so basically when I reopen the program it returns to the previous value.

Ex: if I change the value of a cell to 6 when I reopen the program it returns to its original one for example 2.

Note: I am using openpyxl and Tkinter.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Can you show us the code you've written?

Comment: it is pretty long... and I am new here I dont know how to upload my code.

Comment: here it is : https://pastebin.com/FdzWu1iD

Comment: We don't want all your code. We want you to create a [mcve] directly in your question that has as few lines as possible to illustrate the problem. Show us where you're loading file and where you're saving the file.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dPeWK4iu here it is!

Comment: I am trying to modify a cell in an existing spreadsheet.

Answer (score -1):

To fix it I had to add this:
wb.save("Products.xlsx")
Thx Everyone!